# Circumvent getImageData using Django

Tags: django, image, cors, django-cors-headers

So I want to do pixel manipulation in my Django app, and I want the user to be able to provide links to their own image files. I already saw several solutions, including proxy servers, but I can't seem to get any of them to work, and most of them are specifically for JSON and not images.

The latest one I tried involves using the django corsheaders plugins that adds the cross origin resource sharing headers to responses, but I'm unsure as to what responses exactly are—I'm pretty new to servers.

In any case, this is the error I keep running into:

```
ImageEditor.js:509 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

I'm looking for some way to serve images from other domains onto my website and to manipulate their pixels.

Thanks in advance, and please, explain it as though I was someone who doesn't understand anything about servers. :D